# join two string - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, swift5

i have an application for my shop and in the cart viewController i have a tableView cell showing the user what they add to the cart and i want to join the number of items with the name, i tried this code and it works 100% but instead of showing it like this --> item1 (3 piece), item2 (4 piece), item3 (9 piece) .. it is show it like that item1,item2,item3 (349)

this is my code for the tableViewController

```
import UIKit


class cartTableViewController: UITableViewController {



@IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var totalOrder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var cartTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
  
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    priceLabel.text = "\(userData.selectedItemsPrice())"

   totalOrder.text =  "\(userData.allItemsToString()) (\(userData.allItemsToAmount())" // this is the line i use it  

 
    
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
}
```

struct code:

```
import UIKit

struct userData {
static var selectedItem: Item? = nil
static var selectedItems: [Item] = []


static func allItemsToAmount() -> String {
    var allAmount: [String] = []
    for item in selectedItems {
        allAmount.append(item.amount)
    }
    return allAmount.joined(separator: "")
}

static func selectedItemsPrice() -> Double {
    var result: Double = 0
       for item in selectedItems {
        result = result + item.price
       }
       return result

}


static func storeName() -> String {
    var Store: [String] = []
    for item in selectedItems {
        Store.append(item.Store)
    }
    
    return Store.joined()
    
    
}


static func allItemsToString() -> String {
    var allNames: [String] = []
    for item in selectedItems {
        allNames.append(item.name)
    }
    
    return allNames.joined(separator: ","  )

    
}


}

struct Item: Equatable {
/// All of the animals
static let items : [Item] = {
    let bear: Item = .init(image: UIImage(named: "bear"), name: "bear", price: 1, amount: "", Store: "")
    return [bear]
    
 
 
}()

var image: UIImage?
var name: String
var price: Double
var amount: String
var Store: String
}
```

Comment: Post the full code, especially `allItemsToString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply solved as

```
totalOrder.text = selectedItems.map { "\($0.name) (\($0.amount) piece)" }.joined(separator: ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending all items together and all price together you are getting the result you posted.
Inorder to get the result you are expecting you need to change your code to something like this in user data

```
static func allItems() -> String {
   var allItem: [String] = []
   for item in selectedItems {
       let text = "\(item.amount) (\(item.amount))"
       allItem.append(text)
   }
   return allItem.joined(separator: ", ")
}
```